# OAUTH2 Hybrid Flow or Authorisation Code Flow for Web Application to 3rd party Application Access Control?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a web application written in MVC 5 Asp.Net 4.7, C# on Azure App Service. I want to integrate it with a 3rd party web application, via its API, using OAUTH2 whereby the server application punches out to it, causing its Identity Server to acquire user credentials and then to finally issue a Refresh and Access token so my application can make calls on it API.

Now to my question.... As I understand it the recommended OAUTH code flow for this is "Authorisation Code Flow", however the 3rd party wishes me to use "Hybrid Flow" as they have been advised this is more secure. Is this correct? I emphasise this is a web server to web server interchange, apart from the redirection by the 3rd party identiry server for user credentials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hybrid flow is an OpenId Connect flow, not OAuth2.0. OpenId Connect is an extension of OAuth2.0 both Hybrid and Authorization code are secure as 1) the client has to be able to keep a secret and use it for authenticating its requests 2) the tokens are requested/sent by back-channel (server 2 server communication)